# NSPredicate fetch coredata

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data

I have two linked types in my CoreData model.

**FlightRecording** and **AHRSMessage**

One **FlightRecording** links to many **AHRSMessages**.

I've been fetching each recording and iterating through its linked messages:

`for (__weak id msgObj in rec.ahrsMessages) {`

and have not been seeing the performance I'd like.  As I'm fetching the actual recording objects and not the messages I don't believe I can set a batch size on the fetch so I was thinking i'm better off fetching the messages using a correct predicate format.

Assuming I have a `NSManagedObjectID` for my flight recording is there a quick way to do a  predicate query on my `AHRSMessage`

I've gotten this far which isn't that far:

```
NSFetchRequest *msgFetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"AHRSMessage" inManagedObjectContext:context];
```

And then i wasn't sure what to do for my predicate.  Do I have to match on an actual field such as:

`"ANY flightRecordings = %@"` or something like that?

Do I have to reference a specific field in flightRecording or is there a way to just match on the ID?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If "flightRecordings" is a *to-many* relationship from the **AHRSMessage** entity to
**FlightRecording** then this should work:

```
NSManagedObjectID *flightRecordingId = ...;
NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:@"AHRSMessage"];
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"ANY flightRecordings = %@", flightRecordingId];
[fetchRequest setPredicate:predicate];
```

The argument of the `"ANY flightRecordings = %@"` predicate can be a `FlightRecording` object *or* a `NSManagedObjectID` of a `FlightRecording` object.

Comment: I will try this out shortly!  Thanks

Comment: Thanks -> didn't solve my underlying problem but it worked correctly.